# Downloading images from multiple URLs in R

Tags: r

Thanks to everyone who helped me with my previous query!

I have another question about how to proceed to download those images utilising the loop function!

I would like to **download images** from my data frame which consists of URL links that point directly to a **.jpg image** all at once.

I've attached the current code below:

This is the current code to load the URLs

```
# load libraries and packages
library("rvest")
library("ralger")
library("tidyverse")
library("jpeg")
library("here")

# set the number of pages
num_pages <- 5

# set working directory for photos to be stored
setwd("~/Desktop/lab/male_generic")

# create a list to hold the output
male <- vector("list", num_pages)

# looping the scraping, images from istockphoto
for(page_result in 1:num_pages){
  link = paste0("https://www.istockphoto.com/search/2/image?alloweduse=availableforalluses&mediatype=photography&phrase=man&page=", page_result)
  male[[page_result]] <- images_preview(link)
}

male <- unlist(male)
```

I only figured out how to download one image at a time, but I would like to learn how to do it all at once:

```
test = "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1028900652/photo/man-meditating-yoga-at-sunset-mountains-travel-lifestyle-relaxation-emotional-concept.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=96TlYdSI8POnOrcqH10GlPgOeWFjEIoY-7G_yMV4Eco="

download.file(test,'test.jpg', mode = 'wb')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num_pages = 10 # write the number of pages you want to download
link = paste0("https://www.istockphoto.com/search/2/image?alloweduse=availableforalluses&mediatype=photography&phrase=man&page=", 1:num_pages)
sapply(link, function(x) {
  download.file(x,
                destfile = paste0("C:/Users/USUARIO/Desktop", # change it to your directory
                                  str_extract(x, pattern = "[0-9]{1,2}"), ".jpg"),
                mode = "wb")
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However, it doesn't seem to work, does it work on your end? No photos are being download for me!

Comment: No, it doesn't download photos. But I think it's because of the link you've posted. If you google [your link](https://www.istockphoto.com/search/2/image?alloweduse=availableforalluses&mediatype=photography&phrase=man&page=1), you'll see that in order to download any photo you have to register to iStock.

Comment: What about downloading it from the direct URL address of each photo (i.e., having a code that loops through the existing data frame). Would that be possible?

Comment: Yes, I think so! You could have one .txt file with the URLs of all the images that you want to download, and then you can declare the variable `link` as a vector of this links. That is:
link <- read.table("file_with_all_links.txt")
sapply(link$V1, function (x) {...})